# how to calculate C for lm7809?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, lm78xx, calculation

I need to use a LM7809 to reduce 12-14V to 9V  , the device is using 40mA at normal state

when I search google for application circuit -  I got all kind of valus for Cin , Cout.   use this datasheet
[LM78xx datasheets](http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/LM7805.pdf)

I saw in page 22 to use 0.33uF and 0.1uF - so can I use this ?

what is the thumb rule for it? and what is the formula I need to use?

Thanks ,

Comment: 2A is too much for an LM7809, it will current-limit.

Comment: didn't read the datashet correct . it use max 100mA , normal use is ~ 40mA

Comment: @Afik_Android then **edit** your question please to correct the values. Also, the information on which in- and output capacitors to use is usually part of the LM78xx datasheet – but there's many different datasheets for these out there, so please add a link to the LM78xx datasheet you've read!

Comment: You should read the datasheet. It will tell you the values or how to calculate them.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany The datasheet states the max current output as 2.2A?

Comment: @ChristopherDyer first page, first sentence: "Output Current up to 1 A"; you're reading the "peak current" entry. Sadly, they don't specify how long a "peak" can last, but really, with 65 °C/W of thermal resistance 2.2 A @ 5 Vout-Vin means 11 W·65 °C/W = um, waay waay wayyyyyy too hot for anything that I'd call a "load".

Comment: I change the post - the device is using ~ 40mA and not 2A

Comment: @ChristopherDyer 2.2A "typical" is at an unrealistic 25°C Tj. When it's hot as a pistol (as it surely will be under those conditions) it will typically limit at well under 2A (1.5A at max Tj) and much less than that worse-case. It  might be a useful number for other purposes such as determining whether a short will damage something or for a pulsed load with low average current.

Comment: Ah, I was reading the datasheet I coincidentally already had open and it's slightly different to the one provided in the question. There's no mention of 1A just "typical maximum output" of 2.2A. There's also no mention of junction temperature resistance either. I'm using a poor datasheet.

Comment: @Afik_Android ah, yeah, you should be perfectly able to use these capacitors, or anything larger.

Comment: OK , but is ther any logic for it ? I mean if I will use Cin = 0.2uF  and Cout = 0.5uF (for example) what it will do  ? and what it will change ?